# Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:

Tags: ssl, cxf, sslhandshakeexception

I am working on integrating Webservice which has 2 way SSL.
One such service from same client is already integrated and works fine.

I mean Application A is already integrated with WS 1 hosted on Application B, it's working now.
Now I am integrating Application A with WS 2 hosted on Application B

The same keystore and truststore are in used for both services.

WS 1 works fine, WS 2 fails, I have no real clue of how this could happen. Details of SSL debug logs are below.

I verified the Cipher Suite it is same for both Webservices.

SSL Debug Logs for Failed SSL HandShake - WS 2:

Here I add appropriate ssl log, the difference I found between ssl logs for working service and service which is failing is the **certificate chain** is not sent by client.

```
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 0D                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 13
0000: 0D 00 00 05 02 01 02 00   00 0E 00 00 00           .............
tomcat-http-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 13
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 9
0000: 0D 00 00 05 02 01 02 00   00                       .........
*** ServerHelloDone
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 4
0000: 0E 00 00 00                                        ....
***** Certificate chain
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1**
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 269
0000: 0B 00 00 03 00 00 00 10   00 01 02 01 00 4C 1E 64  .............L.d
0010: 17 BD D1 EC E9 14 82 08   12 17 01 1F 78 A0 6A 40  ............x.j@
0020: 16 24 A4 0D 54 B6 F4 CF   B5 BB A0 BF 32 CD F5 BC  .$..T.......2...
0030: EF 14 3C 8B 9B 72 7A 6D   27 93 59 6A AD 11 82 07  ..<..rzm'.Yj....
0040: 37 8C 68 01 EF 20 D6 0B   00 F4 0B 72 1F DE 0C 28  7.h.. .....r...(
0050: B9 47 D2 39 AB B6 E8 72   B9 6D A7 3F 0C F0 3F 1F  .G.9...r.m.?..?.
0060: 3C CE 3C A2 E3 D6 CB 9D   BA 5D 93 AF 26 B4 D2 83  <.<......]..&...
0070: 68 7A D2 6B 9A 10 D6 A3   95 36 D7 C1 0F C6 F4 79  hz.k.....6.....y
0080: F9 8F 3D 4D 8C D0 E0 46   E2 5A 32 46 42 19 60 09  ..=M...F.Z2FB.`.
0090: 62 15 EE F8 5C 24 A8 78   27 CD A6 22 5F 5E 94 35  b...\$.x'.."_^.5
00A0: 6B 95 C6 42 34 4B D0 98   74 DE 92 9C 8E 79 0E 3A  k..B4K..t....y.:
00B0: 07 D6 17 63 E0 CE CE 8A   C0 26 A5 51 A7 E4 35 8A  ...c.....&.Q..5.
00C0: 5B 2F 1C A6 3A 0B 49 65   24 24 DC F8 39 42 80 38  [/..:.Ie$$..9B.8
00D0: 03 0D 49 F4 61 32 90 8B   BC B6 46 47 6E C0 8B C5  ..I.a2....FGn...
00E0: 00 2F 3D AB 56 5E 04 6A   AD 27 D2 39 A3 22 C5 CB  ./=.V^.j.'.9."..
00F0: 9D D5 8C 47 B7 89 D1 C2   C2 CC AE F7 ED 4D 97 2F  ...G.........M./
0100: 4E 4B AA 2A C5 96 A9 2C   4B 28 E0 09 44           NK.*...,K(..D
tomcat-http-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
[Raw write]: length = 274
0000: 16 03 01 01 0D 0B 00 00   03 00 00 00 10 00 01 02  ................
0010: 01 00 4C 1E 64 17 BD D1   EC E9 14 82 08 12 17 01  ..L.d...........
0020: 1F 78 A0 6A 40 16 24 A4   0D 54 B6 F4 CF B5 BB A0  .x.j@.$..T......
0030: BF 32 CD F5 BC EF 14 3C   8B 9B 72 7A 6D 27 93 59  .2.....<..rzm'.Y
0040: 6A AD 11 82 07 37 8C 68   01 EF 20 D6 0B 00 F4 0B  j....7.h.. .....
0050: 72 1F DE 0C 28 B9 47 D2   39 AB B6 E8 72 B9 6D A7  r...(.G.9...r.m.
0060: 3F 0C F0 3F 1F 3C CE 3C   A2 E3 D6 CB 9D BA 5D 93  ?..?.<.<......].
0070: AF 26 B4 D2 83 68 7A D2   6B 9A 10 D6 A3 95 36 D7  .&...hz.k.....6.
0080: C1 0F C6 F4 79 F9 8F 3D   4D 8C D0 E0 46 E2 5A 32  ....y..=M...F.Z2
0090: 46 42 19 60 09 62 15 EE   F8 5C 24 A8 78 27 CD A6  FB.`.b...\$.x'..
00A0: 22 5F 5E 94 35 6B 95 C6   42 34 4B D0 98 74 DE 92  "_^.5k..B4K..t..
00B0: 9C 8E 79 0E 3A 07 D6 17   63 E0 CE CE 8A C0 26 A5  ..y.:...c.....&.
00C0: 51 A7 E4 35 8A 5B 2F 1C   A6 3A 0B 49 65 24 24 DC  Q..5.[/..:.Ie$$.
00D0: F8 39 42 80 38 03 0D 49   F4 61 32 90 8B BC B6 46  .9B.8..I.a2....F
00E0: 47 6E C0 8B C5 00 2F 3D   AB 56 5E 04 6A AD 27 D2  Gn..../=.V^.j.'.
00F0: 39 A3 22 C5 CB 9D D5 8C   47 B7 89 D1 C2 C2 CC AE  9.".....G.......
0100: F7 ED 4D 97 2F 4E 4B AA   2A C5 96 A9 2C 4B 28 E0  ..M./NK.*...,K(.
0110: 09 44                                              .D
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 93 71 B9 48 72 57   3D 0A BB 31 75 96 FD 0D  ...q.HrW=..1u...
0010: CA 96 42 DD C9 44 B7 A8   B1 F1 A9 C1 C3 27 9F 5F  ..B..D.......'._
0020: 9D 52 23 E3 36 AC EA A5   3A 05 1F F8 8D 5D 14 21  .R#.6...:....].!
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 53 8F 60 0E 0B DC B6 61   EB F5 3D C8 8C 7E 62 6D  S.`....a..=...bm
0010: 5C 42 CB 7A 31 BC B0 0B   D5 6F 0F B2 3C D7 3D A2  \B.z1....o..<.=.
Server Nonce:
0000: 53 8F 60 0E 6A EF 4B 22   15 D3 FB 2B 47 60 66 59  S.`.j.K"...+G`fY
0010: 95 FF 2F 5A 5E CD 24 FD   AB BC 53 DA AE DE EE 6E  ../Z^.$...S....n
Master Secret:
0000: 81 91 2E C9 84 28 03 2A   96 B7 50 3F 4E A6 F6 6D  .....(.*..P?N..m
0010: BA E6 A3 97 90 BA 36 43   7F CC 09 DC 6C 49 23 2A  ......6C....lI#*
0020: 08 F9 9A 28 37 E9 6A 7D   A7 3D DF 5C 1D EE B8 C8  ...(7.j..=.\....
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 02 6B 86 CF 08 1C F8 E1   3F 37 56 C3 E9 56 AF 7E  .k......?7V..V..
0010: 8C AA 30 AD                                        ..0.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 60 3E 08 7B D0 B4 23 48   79 D9 56 4E 98 17 AD 9D  `>....#Hy.VN....
0010: E1 DA 9D 33                                        ...3
Client write key:
0000: 42 6D F6 86 E0 A5 CD 25   C1 32 EB C0 40 82 70 7C  Bm.....%.2..@.p.
Server write key:
0000: 3D 28 B3 C1 E6 23 94 5F   3E F9 66 77 B1 42 EE AF  =(...#._>.fw.B..
Client write IV:
0000: D1 AF 77 1A 7B 63 55 99   0D 20 EA 5F C9 35 C8 33  ..w..cU.. ._.5.3
Server write IV:
0000: 69 95 12 2F F0 85 8D 2B   8F 1F 96 73 A6 1A D7 10  i../...+...s....
tomcat-http-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 69, 40, 167, 235, 209, 255, 39, 90, 171, 21, 67, 200 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 45 28 A7 EB   D1 FF 27 5A AB 15 43 C8  ....E(....'Z..C.
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 48
0000: 14 00 00 0C 45 28 A7 EB   D1 FF 27 5A AB 15 43 C8  ....E(....'Z..C.
0010: F5 F5 5A E3 50 8B BE B4   0A 9C 72 2E FA D7 A2 CD  ..Z.P.....r.....
0020: 9A AB 6B FD 0B 0B 0B 0B   0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B 0B  ..k.............
tomcat-http-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 48
tomcat-http-1, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
tomcat-http-1, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
tomcat-http-1, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
tomcat-http-1, called closeSocket()
tomcat-http-1, Exception while waiting for close javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
tomcat-http-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
tomcat-http-1, called close()
tomcat-http-1, called closeInternal(true)
```

Please help me if you find any clue of what's going wrong here.

Comment: Please provide a bit more of the log, before the beginning of what you have. I'd like to know what the previous handshake message was, either received or sent.

Comment: Hi EJP, I added more logs, let me know if this gives any idea on the issue.

Comment: It looks like you haven't sent or received any data on this connection. You've just done the handshake and then closed it. I've seen that cause problems. If you're not sure for some reason whether you're going to send or receive anything, don't call startHandshake(). It gets called automatically on the first I/O anyway. So, if you just close it straight away, there is no handshake and no way this problem can arise.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files + importing ca certificate. Just importing certificate did not work.